# wooCommerce products displayed incorrectly

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I'm creating a child theme for the "Storefront" theme in wooCommerce. Though, the products gets displayed strange (see photo below). Thanks in advance.

[image]

CSS

```
.products {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 500px;
}

ul.products li.product {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.product img {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.products li.product img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    color: #323332;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

ul.products li.product .woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.products li.product p {
    color: #323332;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
}

.price {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    color: #323332;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.price span {
    color: #323332;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.product-sidebar-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 500px;
    top: 80px;
}

.onsale {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #E02D0D;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
}

.price ins span {
    color: #E02D0D;
}
```

EDIT: They are supposed to display in row, with two products on every line. The first two and two last are displayed correctly, while the yellow product (product 2) don't have any product beside.

Comment: Can you explain how the products are supposed to display?

Comment: They are supposed to display in row, with two products on every line. The first two and two last are displayed correctly, while the yellow product (product 2) don't have any product beside.

Comment: Try to use this jQuery plugin https://packery.metafizzy.co I always use them to solve these problems